# Path Homotopy With Trivial and Discrete Topologies

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be any two paths in a topological space $X$ with the same initial points and the same final points.

1. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are path homotopic if $X$ has the discrete topology.
2. Prove that $A$ and $B$ are path homotopic if $X$ has the trivial topology.

I know that I need to find a continuous map $F: [0,1] \times [0,1] \xrightarrow{} X$ such that
$$F(s,0) = A(s), \quad F(s,1) = B(s) $$
$$F(0,t) = x_0, \quad F(1,t) = x_1$$
for each $s \in [0,1]$ and $t \in [0,1]$.

What do I need to do from here? Do I just need to find specific examples of maps that are continuous and satisfy the given properties? How do I account for the different topologies on $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $X$ has the discrete topology.

In that case all paths are constant. To see this, let $u : [0,1] \to X$ be a (continuous!) path. The image $X' = u([0,1])$ is connected and discrete. Assume that $X'$ contains two distinct points $x_1, x_2$. Then $X'$ is the union of the two disjoint open subsets $\{x_1\}$ and $X' \setminus \{x_1\}$. This is a contradiction because $X'$ is connected.

Therefore, if $A$ and $B$ are two paths with the same initial points and the same final points, they must be the same constant map, i.e. $A = B$. Trivially they are path homotopic.

2. $X$ has the trivial topology.

In that case *all maps* $F: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to X$ are continuous which proves that $A, B$ are path homotopic.